# Reasons for closing this question

Tags: discussion, scope

The question below is on the brink of being closed, probably due to being a "shopping" question. I strongly disagree. It's not about specific brands, it's not going to be outdated any time soon. It's about general information about a device often used, but often not understood.

We still suffer from trigger happy users, in my mind. This behaviour will make new users less inclined to contribute. Getting your first question shot down for no good reason is discouraging.

[How does a DI box work together with guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25680/advice-on-di-box)

We can see that there is good information in the answers, which would have been lost if it was closed. If there is doubt, we should wait and see how the question and answers develop. In this case there was a lot of doubt, since it was an on topic question from the start.

Comment: People mistook it for a shopping question which it never was, it just wasn't worded the best. All the OP wanted was to know  a little more about DI boxes.

Comment: @Dom: This could have been discovered by an easy read. Or avoided by a live and let live mindset. People want the satisfaction of pushing the close button, it seems. We were never flooded with off topic questions during my time here. The bad ones deserve to get closed, but there's too much collateral damage.

Comment: Giving it a useful title along with your edit likely would have helped.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I think it's useful. The guy wants advice on a DI box, that's better than a lot of the questions that were not challenged. It can be improved, though.